# Decrease initial web app load time

Tags: javascript, html, css, http, web-applications

I am creating a one page web app with ExtJS.

Isn't the best way to decrease load time of an web app to inject JS, CSS and HTML in the initial HTML file sent to browser instead of just including the script and css tags to load the files from the server one at a time since that will reduce multiple HTTP requests into only one.

Comment: If you have separate files for static content, then they can be cached by the browser.

Comment: I doubt it. You have to account for browser caching, which makes loading static resources much faster across multiple pages.

Comment: @Pointy: But still that will make each user having to wait for all files to be loaded from the server the first time. And if they refresh it without caching then they have to wait longer again.

Comment: True, but it's also true that browsers initiate concurrent HTTP requests.

Comment: @Pointy: It's mostly true for CDNs, because proper behaving browser should initiate no more than 2 concurrent requests per host

Comment: @friendzis many modern browsers will do [up to 6 or even more concurrent connections.](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network)

Comment: @Pointy 1) When I've said "proper behaving", I meant http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt Section 8 2) That still leaves us with limited amount of parallel downloads. As far as I know, "parallelness" is mostly increased, because now days most of Internet connections are shared at ISP level (be it home provider or router farm for enterprise) which leaves us with wait times for small files much longer than download times.

Answer (score 1):

You may like the concept of httpcombiner.ashx.

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/HttpCombiner

This tool can also compress and cache your js and css

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cut down on initial load time, one of the best ways is to take advantage of the browser cache.  Suggest you look at using a hosted ExtJS library, such as from Google Ajax APIs.  There is a great chance a prospective visitor will already have it cached.

This is just one tip of many.

Answer (score 0):

This webpage outlines some best practices when it comes to lowering perceived webpage loading time.

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

In addition to using the condensers pavan suggested, you can use Google's closure compiler to minimize javascript files.

http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is big difference between load time and ***observed*** load time. One of the best ways to reduce load time is to use server side compression. However, progressive loading appears to be loading faster for the user.
Therefore initial response should only contain minimal set of style sheets (lets browser render later arriving stuff already styled) and layout. Then you could have onLoad callback to some AJAX loader which loads additional components.
Most importantly do not forget to size your image containers. One of the most annoying things is when you miss-click a link just because an image started loading and changed the layout.